# Firestore security rules email_verified not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, angularfire, firebase-security

If I create a new user with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, even though I didn't verify the mail yet, that user is already logged in. And his `.emailVerified === false`, and until here all good.

Now, I go to the mail, verify it using the link, go back to the web app, it is still `.emailVerified === false` so I refresh the page, now `.emailVerified === true`.
So I try to reach this doc:

```
  public async getPublicUserDetails() {

    const currentUserId = this._angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;

    try {

      const docRef = this._angularFirestore.collection("users").doc(currentUserId).ref;
      const doc = await docRef.get();

      if (!doc.exists) {
        return null;
      }

      return doc.data() as IPublicUserDetailsDto;
    }
    catch (error) {

      console.error("User " + currentUserId + " details get failed! " + JSON.stringify(error));
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

It catches an exception, saying I don't have the required permissions to access the doc.

The Firestore rules I'm using are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {

    function dbDocs() { return /databases/$(database)/documents; }
    function isSignedIn() { return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != null; }
    function isEmailVerified() { return isSignedIn() && request.auth.token.email_verified; }
    function isCurrUser(uid) { return isSignedIn() && request.auth.uid == uid; }
    function userExists(uid) { return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(uid)); }

    match /databases/{database}/documents {

        match /users {    

            match /{userId} {
                allow read: if isEmailVerified();
                allow write: if isEmailVerified() && isCurrUser(userId);
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

I can refresh the page infinite times, but it will work only if I signOut & signIn again **OR** if I replace the `allow read` line with

```
match /{userId} {
    allow read: if isSignedIn(); // replace this
    allow write: if isEmailVerified() && isCurrUser(userId);
}
```

Conclusion: it seems like the `request.auth.token.email_verified` does not reflect the value provided inside the `FirebaseAuth` service, as it seems to get refreshed only if I log out and back in.

Can someone help me, please? Thank you all in advance!

Comment: I'd guess that the auth token given to the client doesn't have knowledge of the fact that email was verified until it gets refreshed, which would happen when you sign out and in again.  If you want to avoid having to do this, you could try manually refreshing the token in the client (or waiting an hour) when you think the email is verified. https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/142#issuecomment-301161880